# A book of all ICs?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I was just wondering if there was like a "the holy book" of ICs that contains almost every IC chip with their feature spec included (like the first page of every spec sheets)? Kinda like a dictionary that you can look up?
(Please do remind me of this question is off topic or inappropriate).

I also want to ask the methodology of picking an IC when designing a circuit from scratch, thanks!

Comment: @Jasen may I ask what do you refer to as "not any more"?

Comment: New chips are being added on weekly basis (if not daily). Its difficult to maintain such a catalog. Plus it doesn't make sense to start with an IC and design a product around it. You'd rather want to solve a problem and find an IC for that purpose. When you come to part selection, sites like Digikey can help you where you can quickly look at main features of a lot of comparable products. Then you download the datasheet and go through it in detail.

Comment: It would be much thicker than the "holy books", but they used to publish these for each type decades ago. for a fee.

Comment: Good luck with that. Digikey would probably be the closest thing with the parametric search.

Comment: Those "books" used to be published, bearing catalogues etc etc but since the internet it's all online... Just check out each manufacturer - HINT don't ask us to provide a list of manufatcturers...

Comment: Today it's called "the Internet". :-)

Comment: There was the IC Master books, [see here](https://www.amazon.in/Ic-Master-2001/dp/9991808493). Three thick volumes and out of date the moment it was printed.

Comment: Do you mean publications like [TTL DATABOOK by NATIONAL SEMICONDUCTOR](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_nationaldaTTLDatabook_42712617), found through [project5474.org](https://project5474.org/index.php?title=Databooks)?

Comment: @SolarMike, if you're not going to vote to close, you should make that an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Picking an IC, when designing from scratch? You will reuse the same ICs, because you have learned to trust their behavior. You may even choose the same part number (SN7414 ) because you like the cleanliness of oscillation of BrandXX IC versus the BrandYY IC. New generations of ICs, with smaller faster onchip transistors, will usually have faster edges and cause more interference. I heard of one 16-bit MCU that shut down the ICs around it, because of its radiated energy.

Answer (score 1):

Those "books" used to be published, and very handy too, bearing catalogues etc etc

One issue, as pointed out, was that they tended to be out of date very quickly, but they were always a good starting point. Also, lecturers would base exercises around the use of the books to solve problems as practice for students : tribology has such fond memories...

Since the internet it's all online... Just check out each manufacturer, and some also provide simulation opportunities or links to useful material as well.

HINT don't ask us to provide a list of manufacturers...